# open source python projects

Tags: python, command-line, open-source, command-line-interface

I'm very interested in studying (and maybe contributing to) a open source python project.
I have found Zope to be an interesting possibility.  The only thing which draws me away from it is that I have absolutely no interest in web development.

When looking for a project for this purpose, I come across many; however, I'm deterred by many because they are GUI or web development projects.

Does anyone know of an open source project written in python which focuses on the command line interface?

I have written my own small projects to get experience, but I would like to gain the experience of seeing how an open source project runs and how a large project is managed.

Answer (score 3):

You could go to the [Python Wall of Shame](http://python3wos.appspot.com/), find a project that needs porting to Python3... That would be an interesting way to familiarize yourself with a code base, Python3, and we will all **love** you for it!

Comment: Thanks, I was actually interested in Python3 as well.  None-the-less, it's another great list of projects for me to review.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [IPython](http://ipython.org/) would be a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com)**. It's a huge project and it has been running for several years. It won't be easy (and that's an understatement) to immediately contribute in coding but there are many areas that you could start helping with.